# Angular 1 routing not working - very basic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with set my first angular app with routing. It's very simple and not working.

The URL changing when I clicking at the links

1. index.html - file:///C:/Users/me/repos/angularRouteTest/app/index.html#!/
2. about click - file:///C:/Users/me/repos/angularRouteTest/app/index.html#!/#about

And the content inside ng-view doesn't change

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="swsApp">
    {{1+1}}
    <p><a href="#/">Index</a></p>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
```

```
(function() {
"use strict";

var app = angular.module("swsApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
 template : "<h1>Main</h1><p>Click on the links to change this content</p>"
        })
        .when("about", {
 template : "<h1>About</h1><p>Click on the links to change this content</p>"
        })
        .otherwise({
            template: "<h1>otherwise</h1>"
        })
})
}());
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: You must install a local http server (Apache, IIS) to get it to work

Comment: Is there any error in the console? When you put your code in a codesnippet it works fine, I'm suspecting that Alon is correct

Comment: I think the this `}());` should look like this `})();`

Comment: @Nilesh, both work. I grew up with `})();` but recently read a book where the author used `}());`

Comment: Whoa I did not know that `}());` this works..

Comment: Oh it must be in IIS? I run it from notepad to browers and it should work??

Comment: Okej I installed IIS and what now? I need put this app inside iis "app"?

Comment: Codepen of your code works just fine:
[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpJdrE)

Check your console for any errors, maybe it's a path issue?

Comment: @aaroncrows I saw the link. About goes to `otherwise` adding a `/about`  does work

Comment: @aaroncrows is correct. Your code works for routing... except it should be ".when("/about", {" to get to the about instead of otherwise template.. here in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JKMQj3pLXq0xISveUMUS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't need any web server to launch an angularJS app.

Concerning your issue with your links, AngularJS uses hashbang URLs : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-mode-default-mode-

Hashbang URL mean angularJS intercept only links with the hashbang **#!**

You just have to add this hashbang for each link in you html code :

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
 template : "<h1>Main</h1><p>Click on the links to change this content</p>"
        })
        .when("/about", {
 template : "<h1>About</h1><p>Clicsdfsdfsdfs this content</p>"
        })
        .otherwise({
            template: "<h1>otherwise</h1>"
        })
})
</script>
<body data-ng-app="sws">
    {{1+1}}
    <p><a href="#">Index</a></p>
    <a href="#!/about">About</a>
    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
```

Comment: There is any option to not use '!'?

Comment: you have to add this in your angualr config :        `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');`

Comment: Where I should add it?